# Curl is not installing with ssl support in Centos (at user defined --perfix)

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, installation, centos

There is already a curl & openssl version installed in my system (Centos). I am trying to install curl with ssl support.

**what I've done:**
I have installed **openssl** from git (master) and installed it as follows
`./configure --prefix=/path/to/xyz/dir`
`make`
`make install`

This creates `bin`,`include`,`lib` etc at the location `/path/to/xyz/dir`

Then I have added this path in environment variables
`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/xyz/dir/bin`
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/xyz/dir/lib`

Then I downloaded the curl-7.60.0 from https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.60.0.tar.gz, and trying to install it as:
`./configure --prefix=/path/to/xyz/dir --with-ssl`

But I am not getting the SSL-support as **yes**
[image: CurlSSl]

Comment: When you build `curl` with `openssl` at a non-standard location you have to tell `configure` where to find it. See https://askubuntu.com/q/475670

Comment: Can you add that as answer

Comment: I added this as an answer with some more details. Instead of showing a screenshot it would be better to copy&paste the output **as text** and format it as a code block.

Comment: *`LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/xyz/dir/lib`* - If you set `LDFLAGS` to `-L/path/to/xyz/dir/lib -Wl,-R,/path/to/xyz/dir/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`, then you won't need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build curl with openssl at a non-standard location you have to tell configure where to find it.

Setting `PATH` is for running executable programs, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for finding run-time libraries. These are not sufficient for building. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` may be necessary later for your `curl` program and library to find your `openssl` shared library.

See https://askubuntu.com/q/475670

I didn't check which of the options from the answers are correct. Try

```
./configure --with-ssl --with-libssl-prefix=/path/to/xyz/dir`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure with below parameters.

./configure --with-ssl --with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl